# Angular ngModelChange Internet Explorer 11

Tags: angular, angular-material, internet-explorer-11

I use Angular 4.2.4 and Angular Material 2.0.0.beta.12 and have following form field:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="street" value="{{info.street}}" [(ngModel)]="info.street" (ngModelChange)="formChange()">
</mat-form-field>
```

In Firefox and Chrome everything works as it should and an events fires if I change the input value. But in Internet Explorer 11 everytime the site loads or if I focus the input field the ngModelChange is fireing.

Is there a way to solve this issue? (change) is working but only fires if I focusout the input what is not practicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the suspicion that it's because use use value and ngModel at the same time. It should be either one or the other.
Change to the following:

```
<input matInput placeholder="street" [ngModel]="info.street" (ngModelChange)="formChange()">
```

or try, as suggested by Grobanix:

```
<input matInput placeholder="street" [ngModel]="info.street" (keypress)="formChange()">
```

Comment: I changed the input as you suggested but still the same problem.

Comment: also fires when the page is loaded.

Comment: Maybe hackish, try: (focus)="0"

Comment: Or start = true ....formChange(){ if(start) {this.start = false; return} // the rest remains as it is }

Comment: I now use keypress what is working. thanks for the help!

Comment: That solution doesn't solve the problem. It still fires the event on click

Answer (score 5):

I found out that placeholder attribute is what makes a difference in Internet Explorer. Without it `ngModelChange` works as expected.

The workaround for this case is to put the placeholder in square brackets :

```
 [placeholder]="'placeholder value'"
```

I assume that the placeholder is appended to the input element later (after IE processes it) and that's why IE doesn't fire `ngModelChange` event.

Comment: Unfortunately this suggestion doesn't fix the issue. Does anyone have another solution?

Comment: It was the placeholder for me. BUt adding `[placeholder]` didn't make any difference. Once i removed the placeholder from text area, the events were not triggered

Comment: compiler complains about [placeholder] syntax and I can't find it anywhere in the Angular documentation.  Best here to remove placeholder.

Comment: Crazy that this worked for me. I just removed the placeholder completely. IE11+Angular 11